# DrawingContext DrawGeometry on Canvas (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I try to programmatically draw a rectangle with rounded corners in my WPF project. I'm pretty new to WPF and trying to figure out how drawing works since it's much different than WinForms. I'm using [>this<](http://wpftutorial.net/DrawRoundedRectangle.html) link for the rounded rectangle method (my method is the same as on that website). Here is my code:

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
rect.Width = Width - BorderSize;
rect.Height = Height - BorderSize;

DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
using (var draw = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    DrawRoundedRectangle(draw, new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0)),
    new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0)), BorderSize), rect, new CornerRadius(5, 5, 5, 5));
}

ContentPresenter content = new ContentPresenter();
content.Content = drawingVisual;
previewcanvas.Children.Add(content);
```

This is my output on the canvas:

[image]

Not really what I'm expecting ;) there shouldn't be any text in there to begin with.

Hope someone can help me to draw the rounded rectangle!

**edit**

Some extra info, I need to be able to set each individual corner.

Comment: I think you should render your visual with `RenderTargetBitmap` and then you should assign `RenderTargetBitmap` to `Image.Source`. Then you should add `Image` to `Canvas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        rect.Width = Width - BorderSize;
        rect.Height = Height - BorderSize;
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (var draw = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            DrawRoundedRectangle(draw, new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0)),
            new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0)), BorderSize), rect, new CornerRadius(5, 5, 5, 5));
        }
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
        rtb.Render(drawingVisual);
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = rtb;
        previewcanvas.Children.Add(image);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but I wonder if this would be "the right way" to draw it in an image and then draw the image on the screen, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use RadiusX and RadiusY:

```
  rect = new Rectangle
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.Red,
            StrokeThickness = 2,
            Width = 100,
            Height = 100,
            RadiusX = 25,
            RadiusY = 25
        };
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, startPoint.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, startPoint.X);
        canvas.Children.Add(rect);
```

Xaml:

```
  <Canvas x:Name="canvas"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't allow me to set each individual corner (which is necessary)

Comment: Than this is what you need:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21449/WPF-PartiallyRoundedRectangle-Choose-Which-Corners

Answer (score 0):

After searching I found a much easier solution:

```
Border border = new Border();

border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
border.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5,15,25,35);
border.BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#000"));
border.Background = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#000"));
border.Width = 100;
border.Height = 100;
border.Margin = new Thickness(10);

previewcanvas.Children.Add(border);
```

It's kind of a cheat (since its not a Rectangle), but it works. Here's my result:

[image]